# Flutter scroll to TextSpan child on page load

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of Strings (called sentences) that I want to display as a page (like a book), where each sentence is clickable. For this I have used RichText with a TextSpan as a child that has TextSpan children, where each child is a sentence from the list. Right now I am using `Scrollable.ensureVisible` when clicking on a sentence (using onTap) and the screen scrolls to that sentence. However what I also want is to be able to scroll to a specific sentence when coming from another page, i.e. a bookmark for a sentence.

Question: How can I scroll to a specific sentence in a TextSpan when coming from another page?

```
Widget standardView(AsyncSnapshot<SharedPreferences> userSettings) {
    List<GlobalKey<State<StatefulWidget>>> verseKeys = List.generate(sentences.length, (i) => GlobalKey());

    return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: RichText(
            text: TextSpan(
              //
                children: sentences.expand((sentence) {
                  return [
                    WidgetSpan(
                      child: SizedBox.fromSize(
                        size: Size.zero,
                        key: verseKeys[sentences.indexOf[sentence]],
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextSpan(
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontFamily: quranFont,
                          fontSize: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1!.fontSize! + quranTextSize,
                        ),
                        text: sentence,
                        recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                          ..onTap = () async {
                            await Scrollable.ensureVisible(
                              verseKeys[sentences.indexOf[sentence]].currentContext!,
                              alignment: scrollingAlignment,
                              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: scrollAnimationMilliseconds),
                            );
                          }),
                  ];
                }).toList())));
  }
```

I tried to put the keys globally and use WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback in `initState` to wait for build to finish, and then call Scrollable.ensureVisible, but the currentContext would be null. I also tried ListView (which worked), but I am not able to make ListView show the text as a book page, only as a list of tiles.